# Redirect No-WWW to WWW with Intelligencia.UrlRewriter

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I've an ASP.Net website, in which I use the module Intelligencia.UrlRewriter (urlrewriter.net). I'm having problems using it to redirect a no-www to www, to avoid search engines handle the two urls as two different websites.

I tried the following:

```
<redirect url="http://thetotalsite\.it(.+)" to="http://www.thetotalsite.it$1" />
```

But it doesn't work, or better, it works "sometimes".
For example, if I try to reach:
http://thetotalsite.it
It redirects to www.thetotalsite.it

Instead, if I had something that follows the hostname, for example:
http://thetotalsite.it/a/article-nice-name

It doesn't redirect.

How come?

(N.d.: I use the following rule to handle the url rewrite for articles:

```
<rewrite url="/a/(.+)$" to="/articoli/showarticle.aspx?c=$1"/>
```

)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I solved using the follows I found on another stackoverflow question:

```
    <!-- Ensure that all are on the same top domain and sub domain. -->
<unless header="HTTP_HOST" match="www.thetotalsite.it">
    <redirect 
        url="^(.*)$" 
        to="http://www.thetotalsite.it$1" 
        processing="stop" />
</unless>
```

Note that if you have an outdated version of UrlRewriter.Net, it won't work. Download and compile the latest sources (2.0.0.9).